# Howto use ng-class-odd and ng-class-even in nested ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I'm new to angularjs.

I need to change the CSS of div alternatively in nested ng-repeat.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="aObjects in a">
  <div class="alternateCSS" ng-repeat="b in aObjects">
    <div> some elements </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.alternateCSS:nth-child(odd){  
  background-color: #someColor;
}
```

The above code, applies CSS for all odd divs in 2nd ng-repeat (lets assume the last div is even and CSS not applied in loop), but when 2nd ng-repeat exits and goes to 1st ng-repeat , again comes to 2nd ng-repeat then while iterating 1st time div CSS not applied.

**What I want to achieve :**
  div -------- no background color
  div -------- Background Color
  div -------- no background color
  div -------- Background Color
  div -------- no background color
  div -------- Background Color

**What I'm getting :**
  div -------- no background color
  div -------- Background Color
  div -------- no background color
  div -------- no background color (Problem as 2nd ng-repeat comes for 2nd time  and no CSS applied as it's even)
div -------- Background Color
  div -------- no background color

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First create a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) of your `aObjects` array, which will store its elements lengths:

```
$scope.aMap = $scope.aObjects.map((a) => {return a.length});// mapping rows to their length
```

Then create a custom function `isOdd()` (for instance) in your `$scope` or `controller`, which will receive two arguments: `$parent.$index` and `$index`. This function should return either `true` or `false` if current child element is odd or even respectively. Here is example of such function:

```
$scope.isOdd = function(rowIndex, index){
  let pos = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rowIndex; i++){
    pos += $scope.aMap[i]; // counting summary length of previous rows
  }
  pos += index + 1; // global child element position
  return (pos % 2 === 0); // true if odd
};
```

And here is your template example:

```
<div class="parent-row" ng-repeat="a in aObjects">
  <span>Row {{$index + 1}}</span>
  <div 
    class='child-element' 
    ng-class="{'child-element__odd': isOdd($parent.$index, $index)}" <!-- if odd add class -->
    ng-repeat="b in a"
  >
    Child element
  </div>
</div>
```

Then just create a style rule for `child-element__odd` class.

Here is my **[working plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5RKGIVHhtuwu765fVfBl?p=preview)** (note here I'm using `controller` object to store variables instead of `$scope` which is a good practice in Angular).

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to use `ng-class-odd` and/or `ng-class-even`, but simple `ng-class` with a function which actually tells if the current element is odd or even based on the total length of all internal arrays.

The function could be:

```
$scope.checkOdd = function(parrentIndex, index) {
    var totalLength = 0;
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < parrentIndex; i++) {
      totalLength += $scope.a[i].length;
    };

    totalLength += (index + 1);

    //Here we tell if it is odd within all arrays.
    return (totalLength % 2 == 1);
  }
```

Then in your view:

`ng-class="{'myClass':checkOdd($parent.$index, $index)}"`

And obviously your css:

```
.myClass{  
/**My great class**/
}
```

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/deOPTWeskTbTMwO8sDXP?p=preview) I've created for you.

Answer (score 0):

Nested in your ng-repeat is:

```
ng-style="(($index%2) === 0) ? {'background-color':'none'}:{'background-color':'red'}"
```

This solution takes advantage of the fact that your ng-repeat contains $index. use the modulus to get even or odd.

Alternatively, since the repeater comes with $even and $odd. do

```
ng-style="$even ? {'background-color':'none'}:{'background-color':'red'}"
```

OR

```
ng-style=" $even ? evenStyle : oddStyle "
```

Where
evenStyle and oddStyle in your controller is something like:

```
$scope.evenStyle = {'background-color':'none'};
$scope.oddStyle  = {'background-color':'red'};
```

you'd use the same logic for ng-class
as in
ng-class = $even ? myEvenClass : myOddClass;